# Excel Access Web Part changing my Top Navigation Bar

Tags: web-part, excel

I am a newbie on this site. I am NOT a SharePoint developer or admin by trade. I have accumulated this job with on the job training. I am by far not an expert or claim to be.

My issue is this, when I add an Excel Access Web Part (without pointing to a file), my SharePoint pages and site looks fine with the custom top navigation bar and colors. However, when I attach the excel file in the Web Part, I lose the customization in the Top Navigation Bar. This only happens with the Excel Web Part. No other web part does this.

Here is how the navigation looks like before and after.

[image: navigation before and after]

I have asked our developer and IT team without any luck. I have had my IT contact Microsoft without any luck too. So, if anyone has any ideas please let me know, we are willing to explore any options.

Thank you in advance for your help on this issue.

Henry

Comment: How are you styling the navigation? Is it using CSS or using JavaScript? Is  the customization inside the master page?

Comment: Honestly I don't know...but let me find out..

also, more information is that a consultant created a separate site layout ...this is the layout we are currently using... we are not using the Seattle or Olso....so I presume the separate site layout it is done on the master page.

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm curious what steps the IT took to resolve the issue, if you have that information please share. Here are some potential causes.

1. You are accessing from a different browser than the designer anticipated. Check if another browser has the same issue if you have access to one.
2. If you are using IE, I've seen some weird interactions between temporary internet files, try deleting cookies and temporary internet files.
3. The designer did some custom javascript/css and adding the workbook broke it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

1. Tried it with Chrome and Firefox, same issue.

2. Tried deleting everything, same issue.

3. I believe you are correct.

I did some more testing:

1) Changed to OOTB Seattle layout and the excel web part works fine, with or without a file attached.

2) Changed to OOTB Olso layout and the excel web part works fine, with or without a file attached.

Comment: I found further information from our "consultants" that when they spoke with Microsoft, the step above using the OOTB layout works fine while troubleshooting with Microsoft. So I believe the error or issue is with the coding the consultants did.

I appreciate all the suggestions and help.

Comment: You are more than welcome to give credit to whom you think sufficiently answered your question :)